# How to create Integer object within a class with Generic Integer

Tags: java, class, generics, integer

When I tried the following codes, I get an error:

unexpected type
*required: class
found: type parameter Integer where Integer is a type-variable*

```
class myClass <Integer>
{   
    public void myMethod()
    {
        Integer q = new Integer(5); //Not allowed
    }           
}
```

However, the following codes are allowed

```
class myClass     
{   
    public void myMethod()
    {
        Integer q = new Integer(5); //Allowed
    }           
}
```

Can someone explain why am I not allowed to create Integer object within the class anymore when I declare the class with generic `Integer` ?

**Que:** Is it still possible and how to create Integer objects within the class in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You declared `Integer` to be the generic type parameter, which hides the fact that the *class* `Integer` was in scope.  You can do one of several things to get around this.

Choose a different name for the generic type parameter, e.g. `T`.

```
class myClass<T>
```

Or, fully-qualify the references to the class `Integer`.

```
java.lang.Integer q = new java.lang.Integer(5);
```

Comment: It still shows incompatible type: java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to Integer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong idea of what a parametrizable class is.

To declare a parametrizable class:

```
class myClass <T>
{   
   T myGenericVariable;
   Integer i;
   public void myMethod()
   {
       this.i = new Integer(5); 

   }           
}
```

How to use it:

```
myClass mc = new myClass<String>();//String or whatever you want
```

Comment: What if I need to write this in myClass's method for example addElementToList(T element). When I write addElementToList(5), it gives me error of `required: T`, found: `Integer`. How do you solve that?

Comment: How did you declared your object `myClass` ?